# Read JSON File for Records using Linq

Tags: json, linq, c#-4.0

Following is my JSON file . I have to get Fields mentioned for each page and for each Type in comma separated string. Please help in how to proceed using Linq

Example : If I want "Type = customFields" defined for "page1" , have to get output in comma separated ProjectID,EmployeeID,EmployeeName,hasExpiration etc

```
 {
"Fields": {
"Pages": {
  "Page": {
    "-Name": "page1",
    "Type": [
      {
        "-TypeID": "CUSTOMIZEDFIELDS",
        "Field": [
          "ProjectID",
          "EmployeeID",
          "EmployeeName",
          "HasExpiration",
          "EndDate",
          "OTStrategy",
          "Division",
          "AddTimesheets",
          "SubmitTimesheets",
          "ManagerTimesheetApprovalRequired",
          "OTAllowed",
          "AddExpenses",
          "SubmitExpenses",
          "ManagerExpenseApprovalRequired",
          "SendApprovalEmails"
        ]
      },
      {
        "-TypeID": "CFDATASET",
        "Field": [
          "ProjectID",
          "EmployeeID",
          "EmployeeName",
          "HasExpiration",
          "EndDate",
          "OTStrategy",
          "Division",
          "AddTimesheets",
          "SubmitTimesheets",
          "ManagerTimesheetApprovalRequired",
          "OTAllowed",
          "AddExpenses",
          "SubmitExpenses",
          "ManagerExpenseApprovalRequired",
          "SendApprovalEmails"
        ]
      },
      {
        "-TypeID": "CFDATASETCAPTION",
        "Field": [
          "ProjectID",
          "EmployeeID",
          "EmployeeName",
          "HasExpiration",
          "EndDate",
          "OTStrategy",
          "Division",
          "AddTimesheets",
          "SubmitTimesheets",
          "ManagerTimesheetApprovalRequired",
          "OTAllowed",
          "AddExpenses",
          "SubmitExpenses",
          "ManagerExpenseApprovalRequired",
          "SendApprovalEmails"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: No :( , I'm trying to understand , this is the first time I came across this kind of requirement.

Comment: Well just a hint, but StackOverflow won't write your code for you, but we will help you debug problems.

Comment: Is this homework? I think so, because your previous question is the same, but with XML. The challenge of these two tasks is to reduce the problem to small reusable steps. Step 1 is *deserialization*, i.e. creating objects from filed symbols. The next step is to list their contents. You miss this when you present the tasks separately. The answer to your first question achieves what you want, but is totally XML-dependent. With JSON, you have to start from scratch again. With this in mind, find some JSON (de)serializer and try to list the obtained objects as required.

Comment: (Continued) Then do exactly the same with the XML task, now using an XML serializer, and find out that you *only* have to modify this deserialization step slightly. If at that point you still need help, please come back and show your code so we can help you out.